Response to Deliberately Vague Review Feedback
Background first: I've been crushing it since I landed at this team a year and change ago. The team lead left, I took their responsibility on, and I've excelled--deliberately so, as in tech there is a system of performing at the next level before a promotion. I wasn't expecting a raise or a promotion until a full year of performing really well.
Current situation: I had my annual review a few days ago. No raise, and while I received stellar overall feedback, I couldn't help but notice that the fine print of the areas of improvement were uncharacteristically vague from my manager.
The improvement areas included terms like "drive further impact" and "align better with the broader team roadmap." Quite literally at every step of the process, I've submitted proposals on this for review, and have received no feedback other than "Looks great! Thank you!" and "Makes perfect sense, good work".
Is this dishonest feedback? I mentioned in my review with my manager that this seemed contradictory, and they evaded the question by saying "that's good feedback, I'll take that into account".
I can't help but feel that I have gotten a dishonest review to keep me exactly where I am for no pay increase. Am I being paranoid, or is this a classic move from a dishonest manager? Reading the tea leaves in other posts, it seems to me that when your manager has a cloak of unaccountability, it's time to look elsewhere.
Thanks.

"Background first: I've been crushing it since I landed at this team a year and change ago".  What does "change ago" mean ?  Was it a typo ?

‘A year and change’ means more than a year.  Like ‘a dollar and change.’ It’s a not uncommon idiom.


Is this dishonest feedback?

Probably not.
In many companies, managers are compelled by their boss and/or HR to provide some sort of "areas for improvement", even when they are thrilled with your performance. Often a manager includes such vague feedback because they have nothing more specific to include.
It's simply part of the administrivia middle managers and their teams must endure. No manager I ever knew enjoyed the performance review process.

I can't help but feel that I have gotten a dishonest review to keep me
exactly where I am for no pay increase. Am I being paranoid, or is
this a classic move from a dishonest manager?

When I was a manager, I wanted to get as much as possible for the good performers on my team. I benefited from having a great team. There was no benefit to me for giving them less than they deserved.
But my budget was not within my control. I could ask for whatever I felt was necessary, but if the company said "No", there was nothing I could do. Sometimes, that meant I had to give out less (or even none) to people who deserved more.
Unless you ask why you didn't get a raise, you are just speculating. My guess is that your characterization is incorrect, but there's only one way to know.

While I completely understand your point, I would still quibble about honesty. To me, it would be honest to point this out. I would much rather work with a manager that was up-front about the lack of budget for a raise, rather than telling me that I simply wasn't achieving enough to get one that doesn't exist. That, to me, is still dishonest. Right?

You should ask your manager why you get no raise. It is OK to ask this question.

One of the possible answers is that most if not all employees do not get a raise because the company is not doing well financially this year.
This situation is very rare. But, it is possible.
For example, it has happened before, in the past, at my first company, which had 4000 employees and no employee got any salary raise because the company did not make any profit for that one year. Fortunately, the next year, all employees got a small salary raise as the company was doing better.
BTW, usually, when a company decides that no employee will get a raise, they will send an official announcement to all employees before the performance reviews. This way, no employee will be surprised or shocked.
